# Dividing a square by the diagonals and making each resulting triangle a separate button

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry

Suppose I have a square and divide it by the diagonals resulting in four identical triangles (apart from their rotation).

- **Using CSS/HTML/Javascript, what is the best way to turn each triangle into a clickable area while not splitting apart the encompassing square?**

I have been looking into creating the triangles using image maps (`<map>`), but it seems to me it only works as expected in Internet Explorer.

As another possible solution, I have tried rectangular divs mimicking the triangles by placing gradually smaller rectangles towards the center of the encompassing square from all four "corners of the world". However, that is not an elegant solution, and really not what I'm aiming for, since I want "smooth", not jagged, triangles.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to do so yet, but this would be a good reason to look into the html5 canvas for me.

Comment: The techniques described here: http://www.russellheimlich.com/blog/pure-css-shapes-triangles-delicious-logo-and-hearts/ might be of interest to you.

Comment: I would consider an image map a good solution. It's a proven and reliable technique, that will work in even the oldest browsers with hardly any accessibly issues. Can you show the code you tried? There is most likely just a simple error.

Comment: @Alohci: Interesting idea. However, the page you link to doesn't look right in IE9 or Chrome 10. In FF4 it looks as the author intended (I suppose). Also, I not quite sure how to make borders "hitzones"?

Comment: @RoToRa: Actually, image maps works okay cross-browser if I, in the `<area>` definitions, use `href="javascript:Function()"` instead of relying solely on working javascript on classes assigned to the `<area>` definitions. However, then I have a new problem, which I didn't mention in the initial question: I need to place a visible div on top of/below the image with the image map. I can't get the z-index ordering to work outside of IE.

Comment: @agibsen: IE is usually the one that gets z-index wrong. Is your document in standards mode and does it validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Create a div and style it to be a square. Use a background image to illustrate the triangles
2. Create a variable, square, in javascript to hold the square element
3. Get the position, height, and width of square in your js
4. Do some math to determine the coordinates of each triangle's vertices
5. Write a function, getQuadrant(), that determines which triangle any given point within the square is in
6. Add an event listener to click events on the square. The event listener should call the getQuadrant function
7. Use a switch/case to execute whatever code you need to call conditional upon which quadrant the click lands in

Comment: So, assuming we have (0,0) in the upper left corner of the square and x grows downwards and y grows rightwards, the code for getQuadrant() would look something like:

`if(x < height/2 && x < width-y && x < y) then: top triangle;`
`if(y > width/2 && x > width-y && x < y) then: right triangle;`
`if(x > height/2 && x > width-y && x > y) then: bottom triangle;`
`if(y < width/2 && x < width-y && x > y) then: left triangle;`

I need to test this to see if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Problem solved. :) Thanks, @Adam. My above pseudo code should be correct. I used JQuery to get the position of a click, something like this:
`$('#square').click(function (e) {
                var squareHeight = 100;
                var squareWidth = 100;
                var vertiPos = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                var horizPos = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                getQuadrant(vertiPos, horizPos, squareHeight, squareWidth)); });`

Comment: Cool! Now for your next challenge, figure out how to make each quadrant show animation effects on hover!

Comment: You could probably do that with CSS sprites

Comment: Well, that must be in the next version :)